# How can i handle this promise correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, backend, nestjs

So im using WooCommerce API to bring products of my current wordpress. Im using Nestjs for the backend and Postman to make the requests.

Here's my **Controller**

```
@Controller('game')
export class GameController {
  constructor(private readonly gameService: GameService) {}

  @Get()
  findAll() {
    this.gameService.test().then((data) => {
      return data;
    });
  }
}
```

And here is my **Service** where i make the connection to the WooCommerce API

```
import WooCommerce from '../config/woocomerce.config';

@Injectable()
export class GameService implements GameServiceInterface {
  async test() {
    try {
      const response = WooCommerce.get('products');
      response.then((data) => {
        console.log(data.data);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return `Error! ${err}`;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that, when i console log the promise data field it works fine!, here is the **output**

```
[
gm-commerce-backend |   {
gm-commerce-backend |     id: 10,
gm-commerce-backend |     name: 'Test product',
gm-commerce-backend |     slug: 'test-product',
gm-commerce-backend |     permalink: 'http://wordpress/product/test-product/',    
gm-commerce-backend |     date_created: '2020-12-21T14:27:07',
gm-commerce-backend |     date_modified: '2020-12-21T14:27:14',
gm-commerce-backend |     type: 'simple',
gm-commerce-backend |     status: 'publish',
gm-commerce-backend |     featured: false,
gm-commerce-backend |     catalog_visibility: 'visible',
gm-commerce-backend |     description: '<p>This is a test product for the WooCommerce API connection</p>\n',
gm-commerce-backend |     short_description: '',
gm-commerce-backend |     sku: '',
gm-commerce-backend |     price: '588',
gm-commerce-backend |     regular_price: '2002',
gm-commerce-backend |     sale_price: '588',
gm-commerce-backend |     date_on_sale_from: '',
gm-commerce-backend |     date_on_sale_to: '',
gm-commerce-backend |     price_html: '<del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount 
amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>2,002.00</bdi></span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>588.00</bdi></span></ins>',    
gm-commerce-backend |     on_sale: true,
gm-commerce-backend |     purchasable: true,
gm-commerce-backend |     total_sales: 0,
gm-commerce-backend |     virtual: false,
gm-commerce-backend |     downloadable: false,
gm-commerce-backend |     downloads: [],
gm-commerce-backend |     download_limit: -1,
gm-commerce-backend |     download_expiry: -1,
gm-commerce-backend |     download_type: 'standard',
gm-commerce-backend |     external_url: '',
gm-commerce-backend |     button_text: '',
gm-commerce-backend |     tax_status: 'taxable',
gm-commerce-backend |     tax_class: '',
gm-commerce-backend |     manage_stock: false,
gm-commerce-backend |     stock_quantity: null,
gm-commerce-backend |     in_stock: true,
gm-commerce-backend |     backorders: 'no',
gm-commerce-backend |     backorders_allowed: false,
gm-commerce-backend |     backordered: false,
gm-commerce-backend |     sold_individually: false,
gm-commerce-backend |     weight: '',
gm-commerce-backend |     dimensions: { length: '', width: '', height: '' },      
gm-commerce-backend |     shipping_required: true,
gm-commerce-backend |     shipping_taxable: true,
gm-commerce-backend |     shipping_class: '',
gm-commerce-backend |     shipping_class_id: 0,
gm-commerce-backend |     reviews_allowed: true,
gm-commerce-backend |     average_rating: '0.00',
gm-commerce-backend |     rating_count: 0,
gm-commerce-backend |     related_ids: [],
gm-commerce-backend |     upsell_ids: [],
gm-commerce-backend |     cross_sell_ids: [],
gm-commerce-backend |     parent_id: 0,
gm-commerce-backend |     purchase_note: '',
gm-commerce-backend |     categories: [ [Object] ],
gm-commerce-backend |     tags: [],
gm-commerce-backend |     images: [ [Object] ],
gm-commerce-backend |     attributes: [],
gm-commerce-backend |     default_attributes: [],
gm-commerce-backend |     variations: [],
gm-commerce-backend |     grouped_products: [],
gm-commerce-backend |     menu_order: 0,
gm-commerce-backend |     _links: { self: [Array], collection: [Array] }
gm-commerce-backend |   }
gm-commerce-backend | ]
```

But in Postman nothings shows up. I get a blank page.

This is **Postman** output
[image: POSTMAN OUTPUT]

What do i expect?, i expect the same output that shows in my console but in postman.

Comment: You probably want to `return` that `Promise` in `findAll`.

Comment: But if i return my promise in my controller, i wont be able to handle the promise

Comment: What do you mean by "handling"? You can still have a `.then` in there, and whatever you return in there will be the resolved data.

Comment: so in my service i would do somenthing like
`const response = WooCommerce.get('products'); return response;`

Comment: But then you're not waiting for the promise. Just to be clear, you understand that you can't simply `return` something from `.then` in `findAll` and expect it to be the return value of calling `findAll`? `findAll` needs to return a Promise, otherwise how will you be able to wait for it to resolve? In your service you are already doing that with `response.then`. It's just that you are _not_ returning this Promise in `findAll`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `async`, then return your gamsService promise result in Controller.

```js
@Controller('game')
export class GameController {
  constructor(private readonly gameService: GameService) {}

  @Get()
  async findAll() {
    // you also could not add await, nestjs will help you to get the promise value.
    // it'll work with or without adding await.
    return await this.gameService.test()
  }
}
```

You also need to return the promise in Service.

```js
import WooCommerce from '../config/woocomerce.config';

@Injectable()
export class GameService implements GameServiceInterface {
  async test() {
    try {
      // return all fields
      return WooCommerce.get('products');
      
      // return only header field
      const config = await WooCommerce.get('products')
      return {
          header: config.header
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return `Error! ${err}`;
    }
  }
}
```

Note: you could see [nestjs - Asynchronicity](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#asynchronicity)

Comment: This worked, i've read that nest resolves the Promise, but what if i wanted to acces a specific field of my data, i dont want all my .then data, i want ,lets take as an example: data.header

Comment: Thanks!! it works perfectly now. So just to be clear and for learning purposes, in my controller i should always return a promise right?

Comment: When you add async in front of function, it's all promise value whatever you return.